# horizontal scroll bar in table for making it responsive

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to make a product compare page, as you can see in image, for that all the data is in table, im making individual table for each product by while loop.

and here's my code

```
<div style="border:1px #999999 solid; width:85%; overflow-x:auto; display:flex;" >
             <?php
                if(isset($TotalDiamonds) and $TotalDiamonds>0)
                     {
                            $CStr="select * from mst_diamond where DiamondID IN ($CompareList)";
                                if($CResult=mysql_query($CStr))
                                    {
                                        if(mysql_num_rows($CResult)>0)
                                        {
                                                    $i=0;
                                                    while($CRow=mysql_fetch_assoc($CResult))
                                                    {
                                                        $i++;
                                            ?>
                  <div class="pull-left" >
                    <table  width="100">

                      <tbody class="pull-right">

                      <tr>
                          <th><img src="img/shapes/<?php echo $CRow['Shape']; ?>.png"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $i; ?> of <?php echo $TotalDiamonds; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $CRow['Shape']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $CRow['StoneID']; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $CRow['Symmetry']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo sprintf("%.2f",$CRow['Length']/$CRow['Width']); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $CRow['DepthPercent']; ?>%</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php echo $CRow['DTable']; ?></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td><a> <?php echo $CRow['Report']; ?> </a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?php list($date,$time)=explode(" ",$CRow['Created']); echo $date; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }

                                            }


                                            ?>
            </div>
```

every time table is being repeated in div, now the problem is If i use `display: flex` then  i cant give proper width to `<td>`, i tried giving width to every `<td>` or external  tag.all columns are overlapped,and very small part is scrollable.

If i use `display: block` then width is perfect but if i add more tables then there is no scroll bar is showing.so other tables will be added below the 1st 10 tables.

i have tried zurb table,but it didnt work my need. I have searched SO for similar questions for almost full day, but could not find solution.

i have created a jsbin here. http://jsbin.com/ofiTekeF/1/ 
please take a look at image also to understand what im trying to say.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make `.pull-left` use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` it'll stop your table columns floating under when the screen gets too small if you also give your container `div` the styles `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

```
.pull-left{ display: inline-block; }
#containter-div/*currently styles are inline for this element*/
{
    border: 1px #999 solid;
    width: 85%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It means a lot. I can sleep peacefully now. :P